# Heat energy change in adiabatic process

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

We know that when a system gains heat energy from the surroundings through conducting walls of the container , then the temperature of the system also increase till it reaches an equilibrium value .

Whereas in an adiabatic compression of a gas where temperature increases but the change in heat energy of the system is zero .

It must have some value as the state variable of gas i.e. temp. Changed and also we know that                  ∆Q = s.m.∆T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $Q=C_X\Delta T$, where $C_X$ is the heat capacity under some condition $X$, e.g., constant volume, is useful in telling you how much the temperature of a gas rises if you heat it with incoming energy $Q$ under that condition.

However, there are other ways to increase the temperature of a gas; you can compress it, for instance, as you describe in your question. In this case, you did work $W$ on it and therefore increased its energy by $\Delta U=Q+W$ even though $Q$ is zero for an adiabatic enclosure. Its temperature also increased according to the equation of state for an ideal gas $\Delta U=C_V\Delta T$, where $C_V$ is the constant-volume heat capacity (this equation holds for all conditions).

(As I discuss [here](http://john.maloney.org/cruelest_equation.htm), the similarity between $Q=C_X\Delta T$ and $\Delta U=C_V\Delta T$ has tripped up untold numbers of thermodynamics students who concluded—incorrectly—that $\Delta U=C_P\Delta T$ for an ideal gas at constant pressure.)

Answer (score 0):

The definition of adiabatic expansion is that the heat exchanged by the surroundings and the system is zero.

Also,
∆Q =  ∆U + work done

The work done in an adiabatic process is compensated by the change in internal energy, making sure that no other external factors supply energy to the system.

Comment: "Adiabatic processes are carried out very fast to make sure that no energy is exchanged by the system or the surroundings." This is not necessarily the case for adiabatic processes involving a thermally insulated boundary, e.g., a reversible adiabatic (isentropic) process.

Comment: @BobD I agree. I will edit my answer....

Comment: An adiabatic process does not have to be carried out very fast to be irreversible. An example is a quasistatic adiabatic process with friction